# Can't use :ref: with a Label using Sphinx doc

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I have a problem with using Sphinx-doc's `:ref:` role, I put a label above a paragraph and then I try to link to that label from another doc but inside the same project.

The label I use in one document:

```
.. _hal_1k_1p:
```

And the `ref` I try to use to link to that label:

```
:ref:`Link title hal_1k_1p`
```

But I only get this error message when building the doc:

> WARNING: undefined label: link title hal_1k_1p (if the link has no
>   caption the label must precede a section header)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Okay, looking at [:ref:](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role) you need to have this:

```
:ref:`Link title <ha1_1k_1p>`
```

to link to that label.

Ensure you have angle brackets surrounding your label like so: <label>

Comment: When i read the official docs they give this answer regarding my problem "Labels that aren’t placed before a section title can still be referenced to, but you must give the link an explicit title, using this syntax: :ref:`Link title <label-name>`."
But the problem is that they dont really give an exempel of how to implement it, So im kinda stuck

Comment: also note that the label definition **does** include the `_` at the beginning while the label usage does **not** include the `_` character

Answer (score 2):

### First make sure that your ref is in the format:

**Label**:

```
.. _yourlabel:
```

**Reference**:

```
This is a reference to :ref:`yourlabel`.
```

or (if you want to give it a custom name)

```
This is a reference to :ref:`my very own label <yourlabel>`.
```

The label definition contains the leading underscore (_) while the reference doesn't! Also make sure that you didn't accidentally copy the colons from the label definition (:) to the reference.

### If that doesn't help try switching languages back to english temporarily in your conf.py:

```
language = 'en'
```

If you see that this works you can switch back. Somehow this solved my problem. Maybe related to: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1300